# How to show confirmation message before Opening links in PhoneGap apps in Mobile Safari

Tags: cordova, mobile-safari, sencha-touch-2

I am developing application for iPhone and I have some hyper link in my application.

I want user to confirm By selecting yes or no that whether he/she is sure to open the link or not.If yes then link should open in mobile safari.

I know how to open link in the mobile safari but not able to show confirmation message.
For opening link I am using this code:

```
 document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.srcElement.target === "_blank" &&   
       e.srcElement.href.indexOf("#phonegap=external") === -1) {
        e.srcElement.href = e.srcElement.href + "#phonegap=external";
      }
    }, true);
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please help me.its very important for me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Cordova documentation here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.confirm)

```
if(confirm("Do you really want to do this?"))
{
   dosomething();
}   
else
{
   doSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved:
1. I create custom confirmation pop-up.
2. Then after closing pop-up i open link using

```
 window.open(link+#phonegap=external,"_blank");
```